# Return string in Blazor

Tags: html, datatable, blazor, converters

I have a function that creates an html table from a DataTable. I have attached the code below. Now my question is, how can I convert my string into a HTML code in my Blazor App?

Thanks for your efforts. :)

```
public static string ConvertDataTableToHtml(DataTable dt)
    {
        string html = "<table>";
        //add header row
        html += "<tr>";
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            html += "<td>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
        //add rows
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            html += "<tr>";
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                html += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
        }
        html += "</table>";
        return html;
    }
```

Comment: Don't create a string like this at all. Use Razor syntax instead. Your current code isn't even generating valid HTML - any special character or malicious script content in that DataTable will end up in the final HTML. At best, an `<` or `>` in one of the cells would end up messing up with the table. Worst case, any Javascript stored in the table would get executed

Comment: Okay, i will try that thank your.

Comment: Why did you try to create a string in the first place, when all ASP.NET Core examples use Razor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever you're trying to do, stop.  This isn't the way.  You must embrace Blazor's awesomeness.

It should look something like (I'm not testing this, just to show you the idea):

**TableComponent.razor**

```
<table>
    <thead>
            <tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                <td>@dt.Columns[i]</td>
            }
            </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        //add rows
        @for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
            @for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                <td>@dt.Rows[i][j].ToString()</td>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    DataTable dt {get; set;}
}
```

**ParentComponentOrPage.razor**

```
<TableComponent dt="@MyData"/>

@code
{
    DataTable MyData;  // Do something in override OnInitializedAsync  to fill your table.
}
```

Look at your string building code, and look at the sexy-sweet Blazor equivalent, and know that Microsoft has done the coolest thing to happen to computing over the past couple years! :D

Comment: Some cosmetic suggestions:  `dt` should be `DataTable` , properties often have the same name as their Type.  And   `"@MyData"` can be just `"MyData"`

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I used `dt` so the OP can map what he had to what I did.  As for `@MyData` though-- some habits die hard.  I actually liked it better with the `@` form before, because it made variables pop more-- I really dislike putting variable names in quotations.  I'd recommend the OP make the changes you are suggesting.